# Symfony behind reverse proxy

Tags: php, apache, symfony, nginx, extranet

We have a private network where we have our apps installed on Apache virtual host like:

`http://extranet.domain.com` or `http://calendar.domain.com`

Everything works fine. Now we need to make one of these apps available from outside of our network.

Our only machine with public access is the zimbra (mail) server... where I tried to configure a reverse proxy but it's not working... I added this to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
location /extranet/ {
   proxy_pass http://extranet.domain.com/;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

If I try the external URL from a external network like this:

```
http://zimbra.externaldomain.com/extranet/login
```

I can reach to the login page and login but after the redirect it losses the extranet part of the URL so it goes nowhere... the where I got is

```
http://zimbra.externaldomain.com/home
```

Instead of

```
http://zimbra.externaldomain.com/extranet/home
```

Any help or clue?

Comment: Which route is the login form pointing to?

Comment: http://extranet.domain.com/login is the original login form

Comment: I mean, after the login. Is the form pointing to /extranet/home or /home? The form action should match the proxy_pass location, it's not just automatically passed on

Comment: yap... it is pointing to /home everythin is based on extranet.domain.com and all routes are relative to it... I tried to add a 'extranet' prefix to all routes, but it's not working... and If I can, I don't want to change the current routes... lot of people has some routes on their favorites...

Answer (score 0):

Beware the trailing slash: `proxy_pass http://extranet.domain.com/;`, it is a valid URI.
So nginx will replace your matched request with this.

If your matched location is `/extranet/`, and you pass it with a URI, like `/extranet/someurl`, the nginx proxy pass will replace the matched location with its own URI, in your case `/`.

So, the route `/extranet/someurl` will become `/someurl`.

[For reference](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)